# To prove a the given below set is a generating set in my example

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Consider a set, say $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Let $\mathcal{P}(A)$ be the power set of $A$. Consider

$$ S=\big\{ \{1,2,5\}, \{2,3,6\}, \{3,4,1\}, \{4,5,2\}, \{5,6,3\}, \{6,1,4\} \big\} $$

We have to prove that the set $S$ generate or we have to check whether set $S$ enumerates all the elements of the set $\mathcal{P}(A)$ under the operation *symmetric diference* on $S$ that is taking all possible mutual set symmetric difference between the sets taking $2$ sets, $3$ sets, $4$ sets, $5$ sets, $6$ sets at a time in different order as the operation is not associative and taking all their union and along with it original elements of $S$ to be taken union and the null set.

Should give me the power set or the cardinality of this set should be same as the cardinality of the power set $\mathcal{P}(A)$.

We should not use exchaustive method to prove as it may be small. How to prove this in a mathematical proof?

Comment: It is surprising, but the symmetric difference operation is both commutative and associative.  As it turns out, an element $x$ is in the symmetric difference of the sets $A_1,\dots,A_n$ if and only if the number of sets $A_i$ for which $x \in A_i$ is odd. See the [wikipedia page here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference#n-ary_symmetric_difference).

Comment: In fact, determining whether $S$ is a generating set is equivalent to determining whether the matrix 
$$
\pmatrix{1&1&0&0&1&0\\
0&1&1&0&0&1\\
1&0&1&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&0&1&1\\
1&0&0&1&0&1}
$$
is invertible over $\Bbb F_2$, i.e. whether the matrix has an odd determinant.  The rule for the above matrix is 
$$
m_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{set }i\text{ contains element } j\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Because the determinant of the above matrix is $9$ (which is odd), $S$ generates $\mathcal P(A)$ under symmetric differences.  We could also use row-reduction, which would have a combinatorical analog in this context.

Comment: Understood sir now

Comment: Now that I made the matrix, I see the logic according to which you presented the sets.  In particular, we have
$$
A_1 = \{1,2,5\}, \quad A_2 = \{1+1,2+1,5+1\}, \quad A_3 = \{1+2,2+2,5+2\},
$$
and so forth, where addition is done modulo $6$. Was your question specific to a subset $S$ which is generated in this fashion?

Comment: S but now if the n is large how to prove invertibity directly and check if the matrix has odd determinant n means n is modulo i am taking under

Comment: If you want an answer for larger $n$, you'll have to clarify how exactly you decide which subsets of $A$ are in your set $S$.

Comment: Is the first subset of $S$ an arbitrary subset of $A$ with at most $n/2$ elements?

Comment: I have to go, but this is an interesting question and I hope it gets a satisfying answer.  Good luck.

Comment: Let A={1,2,3.....n}  I take a particular 3 element set S containing say like {1,3,4}  and rotate it under a given modulo n say for some n>= 6 by adding 1 each time and we have to check if the elements obtainted in this fashion generates the the P(A) the of  as suggested in the problem after taking the union with the elements of S and the null set. As dicussed earlier

Answer (score 0):

A counterexample to the statement that such an $S$ always generates $\mathcal P(A)$: if we take $n = 6$ and begin with the set $\{1,2,3\}$, then the resulting $S$ will fail to generate $\mathcal P(A)$.

To see that this is the case, it suffices to note that the polynomials $x^2 + x + 1$ and $x^6 - 1$ have a common root (per the discussion below), which means that the matrix $M$ has determinant $0$, which is equal to $0$ modulo $2$.  More generally, the $S$ produced by starting with $\{1,2,3\}$ will fail to generate $\mathcal P(A)$ for any $n$ that is divisible by $3$.

---

Below are my thoughts on the problem.

The question, as I currently understand it:

> Pick an arbitrary integer $n$, and let $A = \{1,\dots,n\}$. Take $S \subset \mathcal P(A)$ to be the orbit of an initial $3$-element set (for instance, $\{1,3,4\}$) under the operation of adding $1$ modulo $n$.  Will the resulting $S$ generate all of $\mathcal P(A)$ under symmetric differences?

Here is an equivalent formulation:

> Take an arbitrary vector $v \in \Bbb F_2^n$ that has exactly $3$ non-zero entries.  Let $P$ denote the cyclic permutation matrix given by
>   $$
> P = \begin{pmatrix}
>  0&0&\cdots&0&1\\
>  1&0&\cdots&0&0\\
>  0&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
>  \vdots&\ddots&\ddots&0&0\\
>  0&\cdots&0&1&0
> \end{pmatrix}.
> $$
>   Do the vectors $\{v,Pv,\dots,P^{n-1}v\}$ span $\Bbb F_2^n$?

If we take the above vectors as the rows of a matrix $M$, then we end up with the matrix described by
$$
m_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{set }i\text{ contains element } j\\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.
$$
This gives us a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), as exemplified in the comments on the question above.

One approach to answering the question is to compute the determinant of the circulant matrix modulo $2$.  Using the [formula given here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), we find that this determinant can be expressed as follows.  Let $D = \{d_1,d_2,d_3\} \subset \{1,\dots,n\}$ denote the initial set whose orbit yields $S$, and let $f(x) = \sum_{d \in D} x^{d-1}$.  Then we have
$$
\det M = \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} f(\omega^j)
$$
where $\omega = e^{2 \pi i/n}$.  So, determining the answer to your question is equivalent to determining whether the above product (which must be an integer) is necessarily odd.

It is notable that for any $n$, both $f(\omega^0) = f(1)$ and $f(-1)$ will be odd integers.  Thus, they will not affect the parity of the above product.  With that in mind, it suffices to determine whether the product
$$
Q = \prod_{j:\omega^j \notin \{\pm 1\}} f(\omega^j)
$$
is odd.  By pairing conjugates together in the above product, we have
$$
Q = \prod_{j=1}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} f(\omega^j)\overline{f(\omega^j)} = 
\prod_{j=1}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} |f(\omega^j)|^2
$$

Comment: When n is divisible by 3 the orbit fail is their any way to get a n element set S such that number of elements in `$D\,=\,\{d_1,d_2,d_3\}$` but we flip one set between the orbits that can be formed  in such a way that the resulting sets S that can be formed will be linearly independent means a spanning set again as mentioned above determinant becoming non zero. .   Any inputs for forming 3 element subsets of size n divisible by 3 such that in spans.  kind help.

Comment: I do not understand your question